# Maximum length of NumericEditBox and decimals

Tags: c#, decimal

Is there a control for the length of a `NumericEditBox` that takes decimal values into account?

I have a `NumericEditBox` that should't take values larger than 6 digits, but it doesn't take into account the decimal values. In other words 100000 (6 characters) and 100.00 (6 character: 3* ints, 1* decimal point, 2* decimal values) is considered the same length, so setting the `MaxLength` control to 6 doesn't help me.

Any ideas?

Thanx in advance for any help.

Comment: What is a `NumericEditBox`?

Comment: A control that, hopefully, has a MaxValue property.

Comment: Apart from that, you could check `value.ToString().Length`.

Comment: why can't you parse it to double and check if it is > 999999.